# Is it possible to create index page on Tumblr?

Tags: wordpress, tumblr

I found [index shortcode](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/archives-shortcode/) on [wordpress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/) useful. Is there any possibilities to create "index shortcode" page/text on tumblr?

What I found from Googling was not *the index solution* I need.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. The closest you can have is `{block:TagPage}`